# MySQL Unique Key instead of PK

Tags: mysql, performance, database-performance, unique-constraint, unique-key

I have two tables `message` and `hashtag`:

[image]

One message can have multiple hashtags. But without duplicates of hashtags for one message.

`message` table:
[image]

`hashtag` table:
[image]

In table `hashtag` we have to keys, one PRIMARY for `id` and another UNIQUE key (`hashtag`, `message_id`).

**Questions:**

Does this make sense use `id` column in `hashtag` table in case we have unique pairs of (`hashtag` `message_id`)?

In case if `id` it's not necessary, are there some performance issues or other drawbacks?

Comment: In the table hashtag. What makes it unique? Is it message_id by itself or is it a combination with hashtag and message_id? Let me ask a bit differently can on message have one or multiple hashtags?

Comment: @Arion Yes `message` can have multiple `hashtags`. But without duplicates of hashtags for one message.

Comment: So then it is a one-to-one relation?

Comment: @Arion One-to-many, check updates

Comment: Might your `message` table also have [4, food, 3] ?  If so, you need "many:many".

Answer (score 1):

If you have a "natural" `PRIMARY KEY`, it is OK (and often favorable) to avoid adding an `AUTO_INCREMENT` (or 'sequence').

If 1:many:

```
CREATE TABLE hashtag (
    hashtag VARCHAR(6) NOT NULL,
    message_id INT     NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(hashtag),
    INDEX      (message_id, hashtag)
);
```

For many:many

```
CREATE TABLE hashtag (
    hashtag VARCHAR(6) NOT NULL,
    message_id INT     NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(hashtag, message_id),
    INDEX      (message_id, hashtag)
);
```

Further discussion:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#many_to_many_mapping_table

In MySQL, use `ENGINE=InnoDB`, and always have an explicit `PRIMARY KEY`.  Keep in mind that a PK *is a* `UNIQUE` key, which *is an* `INDEX`.

Another issue...  `INT` is always 4 bytes.  `VARCHAR(6)` (assuming English text) takes between 1 and 7 bytes.  Guess what?  `VARCHAR(6)` *may* be smaller, on average.  Hence, it could be wasteful in both space and speed to assign an `INT` id for each hashtag!

Answer (score 0):

You could be right in that you want a `unique` constraint on ID/message ID.

However, without knowing exactly, I think a better design would be

`HASHTAG (ID, HASTAG_TEXT)` ID as PK

`MESSAGE (ID, MESSAGE_TEXT)` ID as PK

`HASTAG_TO_MESSAGE(HASHTAG_ID, MESSAGE_ID)` Both as PK

You might want a "sequence #" too, in which case you'd want a PK on all columns and a unique constraint on both IDs.

Comment: Thanks for answer. What do you mean under _constraint on ID/message ID_ ? I have unique constraint for `hashtag`, `message_id`. :)

By design of DB I what show that `message` table it's important table, if there is no message there is no hashtags, if I'll remove message it will remove all related hashtags by cascade.

Comment: Unique constraint on both IDs is so you don't have the same hashtag on the same message more than once.  If you follow my design then do the cascade delete so it deletes HASHTAG_TO_MESSAGE when you delete message.  If you don't follow this design it means each hashtag has to be repeated for each message it occurs in.  That may or may not be what you want.  It also means you might as well not have the hashtag ID.  My way is more traditional.

Comment: Yes, agree that you way traditional and clear. But please consider my tables design. **Yes, I want repeat hashtag for each message it occurs in**. Do I nedd PK for in `hashtag` table if I have unique key for (`hashtag`, `message_id`) ? If not, are there some performance issues or other drawbacks with unique key solution?

Comment: In that case a) your hashtag & message ID are the PK which is unique by definition and b) you don't need the ID.  I'd not worry about performance.  Not sure if I've 100% understood...